# What is this liquid that looks like dew drops on my brassica leaf margins?

Tags: brassicas

I fertilized my plants today and watered them well. Tonight, when I looked at my vegetable patch, I found tiny drops of transparent liquid on some of my half-grown brassicas. They're on the leaf margins at the place where the veins meet the leaf margins.

What is this phenomenon?

Answer (score 4):

This is called [guttation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guttation).  You can see it on plants grown indoors as well.  The roots send water up to the leaves and under the right conditions the pressure is so much that water comes out of the leaves.  You can find it occurring under conditions of high moisture levels in the soil.  It is harmless and can be enjoyed rather than looked upon as something that needs fixing.